# Complete Orbits in Compact Dynamical Systems

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I am going through a book on topological dynamics, and in establishing their definitions they mention the following 'fact,' leaving it as an exercise:

If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, $x_0 \in X$ and $f : X \rightarrow X$ is a continuous function, then the following two conditions are equivalent:

1) $x_0 \in \cap f^n(X)$, and

2) there is an infinite sequence $x_{-n}$ with $f(x_{-n }) = x_{-n+1}$

In other words, $x_0$ has a complete 'reverse orbit' iff it is contained in the image of every iterate of $f$.  I am not convinced that (1) implies (2) even if $X$ is compact metric.  To see this, attach a straight line segment $A_n$ to the origin in the plane, such that the length of $A_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ with radian angle $\frac{\pi}{n}$.  Then their union is compact metric.

Now, let $B_n = \lbrace b_1^n, b_2^n, \dots, b_n^n \rbrace \subset A_n$ be a subset consisting of $n$ points, each containing the origin.  Let $X = \cup B_n$.  It is compact metric, and we can define a continuous function on each $B_n$ separately via $f(b_k^n) = b_{k+1}^n$, where we assume $b_n^n = b_{n+1}^n = \cdots = 0$, i.e. the origin is a sink for the action on each $B_n$.  Then isn't it true that $0$ satisfies (1) but not (2)?

To avoid the constant sequence being a solution, we can assume that there is a finite tail after $0$ which then becomes a periodic orbit (or anything else with compact phase space).  So these points will pass through $0$ before dumping into a finite periodic orbit.

Thanks for checking!

Comment: To make your last paragraph make sense you need to remove mention of $b_{n+1}^n,...$ and that $0$ is a sink, as the next application of $f$ moves away from $0$. -- Per the topology in the plane and $f$ continuous you necessarily get $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n^n)=0$, as $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n^n=0$ by construction, so that you can not avoid $0$ being a fixed point without greater changes to the example.

Comment: If it is so trivial, why do you not remove the obvious deficiencies of your example? Also note that $\lim b_{n-1}^n=0$, so that by continuity $f(0)=\lim f(b_{n-1}^n)=\lim b_n^n=0$, thus $0$ remains a fixed point and thus a pre-image of any depth to itself, no tails or cycles can spawn off $0$.

Comment: @JohnSamples your behaviour in your comments in unfriendly and confrontational. Please remember that there are real life people reading your comments.

Comment: @dan this person has been posting and deleting erroneous answers involving fanciful things like the axiom of choice, and then insulting me for not 'understanding' their gibberish.  Now they are heckling my writing style.  I see that he has another 'solution' with two up-votes; it is so dreary and depressing.

Comment: His new answer looks correct to me. His explanation for why your example does not refute the statement of the questions also looks correct to me.

Comment: Ah, I see that even his *comments* have been edited.  Though yes, they do appear to finally have pointed out the problem with the construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim of equivalence is true and employs the compactness of $X$ as a critical assumption.

Per assumption of 1), $x_0\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^n(X)$, which means that pre-images $\tilde x_{-n}$ of any depth $n$ exist, $x_0=f^n(\tilde x_{-n})$. By compactness, the sequence $f^{n-1}(\tilde x_{-n})$ has an accumulation point $x_{-1}$, which means that there is a sub-sequence $\tilde x_{-n_k}$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty} f^{n_k-1}(\tilde x_{-n_k})=x_{-1}$. By continuity $$f(x_{-1})=f\left(\lim_{k\to\infty} f^{n_k-1}(\tilde x_{-n_k})\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty} f^{n_k}(\tilde x_{-n_k})=x_0.$$

---

It remains to show that also $x_{-1}\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^n(X)$. Fix some $N\in \Bbb N$, pick any accumulation point $\tilde x_{-1,N}$  of the sequence $$\left(f^{n_k-1-N}(\tilde x_{-n_k})\right)_{k\in \Bbb N,\, n_k>N+1},$$ which exist because of the compactness of $X$. We get that $x_{-1}$ is the image of  $\tilde x_{-1,N}$ under $f^N$, again by continuity. Thus, $x_{-1}\in f^N(X)$, for any $N\in \Bbb N$.

Now apply the same process on $x_{-1}$ to obtain one $x_{-2}$ etc. to obtain a sequence of points with $f(x_{-k-1})=x_{-k}$ as claimed in 2).